# Couldn't add required input in the form

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

The code is:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'mobile', null, array('required' => 'required', 'type' => 'number', 'min' => 0, 'id' => 'mobile', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Eg: 9876543210', 'tabindex' => 15)) !!}
```

I am adding mobile number field in the form, which needs to be filled and should not be an empty and its need to be filled.. Without filling it, it should not move to the next step.. What should i change in the above code to make the field as required??

In the given code `'required'=>'required'` is not working..

Comment: You have to stop creating new accounts and asking the same question again and again.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin You didnt given correct answer for me.. Let others give the right one for me.. I am in the need of answer soon.. And it is not the code which i was asked earlier.. It is the addition of 'required'=> 'required' and i want this one to be clarified..

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I had given the new error in the comment but you have not checked it out, You simply said that its not your error..

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin This is the answer needed by our team its not different account creation.. Its all each ones personal account.. But u interfering and making it duplicate everywhere..